# Remove items from nested array of objects based on a condition

Tags: javascript

In my application, I have data returned from the server like below. It has very deep nesting:

```
var data = [{
    name: "root",
    children: [{
            name: "Parent1",
            children: [{
                    name: "Parent1-child1",
                    children: [{
                            name: "Parent1-child1-grandchild1",
                            children: [{
                                name: "Parent1-child1-grandchild1-last",
                                children:[]
                            }]
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Parent1-child1-grandchild2",
                            children: []
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Parent1-child1-grandchild3",
                            children: []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "Paren1-child2",
                    children: [{
                            name: "Parent1-chil2-grandchild1",
                            children: []
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Parent1-child2-grandchild2",
                            children: [{
                                name: "Parent1-child2-grandchild2-last",
                                children: []
                            }]
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Parent1-child2-grandchild3",
                            children: []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "Parent1-child3",
                    children: []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Parent2",
            children: [{
                    name: "Parent2-child1",
                    children: []
                },
                {
                    name: "Parent2-child2",
                    children: [{
                            name: "Parent2-child2-grandchild1",
                            children: []
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Parent2-child2-grandchild2",
                            children: [{
                                name: "Parent2-child2-grandchild2-last",
                                children: []
                            }]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Parent3",
            children: []
        }
    ]
}];
```

The requirement is to loop through all the objects (deep nested level also) and remove the object if the children property has a value of an empty array. So the **output should be like below**

```
var data = [{
    name: "root",
    children: [{
            name: "Parent1",
            children: [{
                    name: "Parent1-child1",
                    children: [{
                            name: "Parent1-child1-grandchild1",
                            children: []
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "Paren1-child2",
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: "Parent1-child2-grandchild2",
                            children: []
                        },
                    ]
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Parent2",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Parent2-child2",
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: "Parent2-child2-grandchild2",
                            children: []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}];
```

I have tried the following code, but it doesn't work as expected. Please let me know how to achieve the expected result.

```
function checkChildrens(arr) {
    arr.forEach((ele,i) => {
    if(ele.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
        checkChildrens(ele['children']) 
    } else {
        arr.splice(i,1)
    }
    })
}
checkChildrens(data);
```

I have tried with the filter method also in that case. It is not working correctly.

```
arr.filter((ele,i)=>{
   if(ele.hasOwnProperty('children') && ele.children.length !== 0 ){
      removeEmpty(ele.children)
   }else{
        return false;
    }
    return true;
})
```

Comment: Can you show the output that of this code?

Comment: The array filter method might work better for you in this situation.

Comment: You were too close to solution  `if(ele.hasOwnProperty('children') && ele.children.length !== 0)` by checking length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could rebuild new objects by checking the children array length.

```js
function filter(array) {
    return array.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (o.children && o.children.length) {
            r.push(Object.assign({}, o, { children: filter(o.children) }));
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
}

var data = [{ name: "root", children: [{ name: "Parent1", children: [{ name: "Parent1-child1", children: [{ name: "Parent1-child1-grandchild1", children: [{ name: "Parent1-child1-grandchild1-last", children: [] }] }, { name: "Parent1-child1-grandchild2", children: [] }, { name: "Parent1-child1-grandchild3", children: [] }] }, { name: "Paren1-child2", children: [{ name: "Parent1-chil2-grandchild1", children: [] }, { name: "Parent1-child2-grandchild2", children: [{ name: "Parent1-child2-grandchild2-last", children: [] }] }, { name: "Parent1-child2-grandchild3", children: [] }] }, { name: "Parent1-child3", children: [] }] }, { name: "Parent2", children: [{ name: "Parent2-child1", children: [] }, { name: "Parent2-child2", children: [{ name: "Parent2-child2-grandchild1", children: [] }, { name: "Parent2-child2-grandchild2", children: [{ name: "Parent2-child2-grandchild2-last", children: [] }] }] }] }, { name: "Parent3", children: [] }] }],
    result = filter(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Approach for removing all nested empty children (except the last one. This has an empty object, but no children property).

```js
function filter(array) {
    return array.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (o.children) {
            var children = filter(o.children);
            if (children.length) r.push(Object.assign({}, o, { children }));
        } else {
            r.push(o);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
}

var data = [{ name: "root", children: [{ name: "Parent1", children: [{ name: "Parent1-child1", children: [{ name: "Parent1-child1-grandchild1", children: [{ name: "Parent1-child1-grandchild1-last", children: [] }] }, { name: "Parent1-child1-grandchild2", children: [] }, { name: "Parent1-child1-grandchild3", children: [] }] }, { name: "Paren1-child2", children: [{ name: "Parent1-chil2-grandchild1", children: [] }, { name: "Parent1-child2-grandchild2", children: [{ name: "Parent1-child2-grandchild2-last", children: [] }] }, { name: "Parent1-child2-grandchild3", children: [] }] }, { name: "Parent1-child3", children: [] }] }, { name: "Parent2", children: [{ name: "Parent2-child1", children: [] }, { name: "Parent2-child2", children: [{ name: "Parent2-child2-grandchild1", children: [] }, { name: "Parent2-child2-grandchild2", children: [{ name: "Parent2-child2-grandchild2-last", children: [] }] }] }] }, { name: "Parent3", children: [{}] }] }],
    result = filter(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think where this goes wrong when you remove items you also create empty children also the code should run again until no empty children has left.

Comment: @Eldar, sorry op wants empty arrays, as stated above.

Comment: Yeah noticing that took me long :)

Comment: @NinaScholz but this solution is hard to understand for newbies. you introduced `reduce, assign` for new developer which doesn't correctly understand recursion

Comment: @NinaScholz, thank you soooo much. As Eldar told ,if the code should run until no empty children has left means ,how to rewrite the above code

Comment: @codegeek, really? in this case, you get an empty array as result. do you want this?

Comment: @NinaScholz ,In this example i have used the dummy data, But in real time, the data is very huge.in that case i think there wont be a empty result. so just want to know how the code should be in that case. you can just give me the code in the comment itself, it would be very helpful for me

Comment: when should an item kept? at least the last has no children. do you have an example of the data set which reflects missing children and some children who should be in the result?

Comment: Hi @NinaScholz thanks a lot. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-o6UhcDT2NVM3JlVFZXWmpDSEVyYXJYMGtYTUc3NTVYbjVV/view?usp=sharing - my real data

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [{
  name: "root",
  children: [{
      name: "Parent1",
      children: [{
          name: "Parent1-child1",
          children: [{
              name: "Parent1-child1-grandchild1",
              children: [{
                name: "Parent1-child1-grandchild1-last",
                children: []
              }]
            },
            {
              name: "Parent1-child1-grandchild2",
              children: []
            },
            {
              name: "Parent1-child1-grandchild3",
              children: []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "Paren1-child2",
          children: [{
              name: "Parent1-chil2-grandchild1",
              children: []
            },
            {
              name: "Parent1-child2-grandchild2",
              children: [{
                name: "Parent1-child2-grandchild2-last",
                children: []
              }]
            },
            {
              name: "Parent1-child2-grandchild3",
              children: []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "Parent1-child3",
          children: []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Parent2",
      children: [{
          name: "Parent2-child1",
          children: []
        },
        {
          name: "Parent2-child2",
          children: [{
              name: "Parent2-child2-grandchild1",
              children: []
            },
            {
              name: "Parent2-child2-grandchild2",
              children: [{
                name: "Parent2-child2-grandchild2-last",
                children: []
              }]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Parent3",
      children: []
    }
  ]
}];

function checkChildrens(arr) {
  let res = []

  arr.forEach(v => {
    if (v.children && v.children.length) {
      res = res.concat({
        name: v.name,
        children: checkChildrens(v.children)
      })
    }
  })

  return res
}
console.log(checkChildrens(data));
```